# default for sslmode argument while connection to postgres server through JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, require

We are making connections to the postgres server through jdbc and psql (libpq) . I have set the ssl as on the postgres server . It can take ssl as well as non ssl connections.
I made a connection through a psql client to postgres server and could confirm that the default sslmode (when no sslmode parameter is supplied while making connection) is "prefer". Please note i have not supplied the sslmode parameter in the connection string from psql. Still connection is secured

```
psql "postgresql://$POSTGRES_HOST:$PG_PORT/postgres" -U postgres
psql (9.6.18, server 9.6.12)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help
```

.
This means that prefer is default sslmode for psql.
I have read in the AWS documentation for jdbc connections to server  the default mode is "verify-full". I created a jdbc connection to the postgres server by supplying no sslmode to the connection string .passing "verify-ca" and "verify-full" fails to connect to postgres server with no certficate found exception.  The connection was successful . I just want to confirm what is the default sslmode for jdbc connections to the postgres server when ssl is turned on the server. I think it should require or below.

Comment: Why would AWS be documenting JDBC, unless it is an AWS specific implementation?  Could you provide a link to that?

Comment: I am looking at adding SSL to Aurora Postgres Service in AWS. This is the documentation link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Security.html

Comment: Please look at the section "To connect to an Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster over SSL". The exact section is as follows : The default sslmode mode used is different between libpq-based clients (such as psql) and JDBC. The libpq-based clients default to prefer, where JDBC clients default to verify-full.

Comment: The AWS documentation glosses over the real behavior.  The default of behaving as if sslmode were set to verify-full applies only if you specify `ssl=true`. If you don't set `ssl=true` and also don't set `sslmode`, then JDBC behaves as if sslmode=prefer, same as libpq does.

Comment: thanks , i realised that configuring the client for ssl means setting the ssl parameter as true. But is there specific documentation in postgresql site on this . Also how do we test to find out that the sslmode is prefer when both these parametes are not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of the `sslmode` connection parameter depends on the setting of the connection parameter `ssl`:

- if `ssl` is set to `true` or set without a value, then `sslmode` defaults to `verify-full`
- if `ssl` is not set, `sslmode` defaults to `prefer`, much like libpq

I'd like to quote the documentation on that, but onfortunately that becomes only clear when you read the source. See `pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/SslMode.java`:

```java
public enum SslMode {

[...]

  public static SslMode of(Properties info) throws PSQLException {
    String sslmode = PGProperty.SSL_MODE.getOrDefault(info);
    // If sslmode is not set, fallback to ssl parameter
    if (sslmode == null) {
      if (PGProperty.SSL.getBoolean(info) || "".equals(PGProperty.SSL.getOrDefault(info))) {
        return VERIFY_FULL;
      }
      return PREFER;
    }

    for (SslMode sslMode : VALUES) {
      if (sslMode.value.equalsIgnoreCase(sslmode)) {
        return sslMode;
      }
    }
    throw new PSQLException(GT.tr("Invalid sslmode value: {0}", sslmode),
        PSQLState.CONNECTION_UNABLE_TO_CONNECT);
  }
}
```